# GridView record update help needed

Tags: asp.net, sql-update, html-select

I have a table in database.

This table has 10 rows and 4 columns which contains ID( an integer value coming from UI ).

In front end in asp.net application i bind all 10 rows to a Grid-view.Grid-view has 4 column and each column contains a drop-down list.
There is a button called Update on screen.

I want to update database table on clicking on Update button i.e. whatever option is selected in Grid-view should update in database table.

What would be the best approach to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a codebehind handler to handle the button click, then do a database update based on the values in the Gridview.

Comment: yeah i know that i have to do something like you wrote but i am asking what would be the best approach i.e. one by one database update OR update at once OR any other method.

Comment: I would tend to do it all at once, but either way would be fine in my opinion. Ease of coding and maintenance might weigh as much as performance on something this small.